# How to change float precision for ML Model Binding?

Tags: android, android-studio, precision, tensorflow-lite

I want to achieve the same result of `GpuDelegate.setPrecisionLossAllowed` on ML Model Binding but haven't found any solution yet. Any help is appreciated. ML Model Binding is a built-in method of Android Studio that makes using models easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no. GPU options are not exposed when using ML model binding. For enabling the GPU option, please consider using TFLite API, instead. https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/android